# TypeError from Django Cache

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, pickle

**Update**: See "Even Better Solution" below.

This one has me stumped. When I call an HTML page generated by Django REST Framework, it works. When I call it a second, third, fourth time, I get:

```
[26/Oct/2015 15:14:42]"GET /api/rest/v3/dockets/ HTTP/1.1" 500 92424
Internal Server Error: /api/rest/v3/dockets/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/mlissner/.virtualenvs/courtlistener/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 108, in get_response
    response = middleware_method(request)
  File "/home/mlissner/.virtualenvs/courtlistener/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/middleware/cache.py", line 134, in process_request
    response = self.cache.get(cache_key, None)
  File "/home/mlissner/.virtualenvs/courtlistener/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/cache/backends/locmem.py", line 54, in get
    return pickle.loads(pickled)
TypeError: __new__() takes exactly 3 arguments (2 given)
```

Unlike 99% of the stacktraces I get from Django, this one doesn't mention my code at all, and seems to be only code from Django itself.

I'm using the development server, Django 1.8.7, Django REST Framework 3.2.3, and Python 2.7.

My middleware setting is:

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = [
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.cache.UpdateCacheMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.cache.FetchFromCacheMiddleware',
]
```

I've only seen this when looking at Django REST Framework pages. Any ideas?

### Things I've Tried

- Upgrading Django, djangorestframework and djangorestframework-filters.
- Changing my `CACHE` setting so it uses Redis instead of `LocMemCache`. I thought this might help because somebody in the comments said changing it to `FileBasedCache` helped. The change to redis, in itself did not help, though setting it to the `DummyCache` does.

### Solution

[`django-redis-cache`](https://django-redis-cache.readthedocs.org/en/latest/advanced_configuration.html#pickle-version) allows you to set different versions of pickle so I've tinkered with that, given that [one link](http://bugs.python.org/issue3065) hinted at the pickle version being related. At first, this seemed to have no effect, but [I filed a bug](https://github.com/sebleier/django-redis-cache/issues/108) in `django-redis` ("PICKLE_VERSION doesn't seem to work"), which they quickly fixed. Once that was fixed, I set the PICKLE_VERSION to 1, and the problem was solved.

I've also [filed a bug in DRF](https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/issues/3725) to see if there's a better way to get to the bottom of this. However, I'm not sure if the bug is there, in my code, or in Django itself.

### Even better solution

I'm the master at workarounds, it seems. But the good news is that this was a [bug](https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/issues/3628) in Django Rest Framework, which has [been fixed](https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/pull/3701), and will be released in 3.3.2 (hopefully).

Comment: version of Django and DRF ?  are you using django-extensions ? can you post your `settings.CACHE` ?

Comment: @sax: Updated the Q with those details, thanks for your help!

Comment: @sax: I haven't changed `settings.CACHE`, so I suppose it's unset?

Comment: not sure this can help, I had same issue with `CACHE` `LocMemCache `  and all disappeared as I moved to `FileBasedCache`. No idea why and this is not an answer, only FYI.

Comment: Ugh. That's weird, @sax. I couldn't find any other instances of this while searching. Did you have the same Django, REST Framework, Python stack?

Comment: django 1.8.5 - drf 3.2.4. issue happened after upgrade from drf 3.1 and django 1.7;

Comment: Hey did you ever fix this? I'm facing the same issue and I can't find anyone else with the same problem.

Comment: @CorentinS. I found an answer. Take a look if this is still a problem for you.

Comment: @mlissner thanks! You should add your answer and accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This was a bug in Django Rest Framework](https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/issues/3628), which has been fixed, and has been released in 3.3.2.

Answer (score 1):

It is easy to understand why your problem only happens when accessing the page after the second time. That is because when you load the page the first time, the data is fetched from data source (database?), and written into cache. After that, each page load will hit the cache directly.

It seems the problem is related to what type of data is cached. The exception is raised in `pickle` module, when the cached data is loaded from a string, the unpickler detects the type of data incorrectly, and call `__new__` method of that class. That is where the error occurs.

There are some posts talking about the pickle unload error, see if they are helpful:

- http://bugs.python.org/issue3065
- http://www.gossamer-threads.com/lists/python/python/373825

It looks there were issues when pickling a tuple, does the data cached in your app include a tuple?